# How can a screen be projected on a surface which is at 90° with the screen?

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction

What I am thinking may appear to be weird. [image: Here is how it will be placed]

If we use a mirror, I guess, the mirror should be placed at 45° making a Triangle. But that's not what I want. The content on the screen should be visible on the surface but not blocking the front view, how is it possible?

Comment: are you making a Google Glass?

Comment: Almost similar concept, but not Google Glass

Comment: I think it requires lenses to focus the incoming light properly. Your eyes won't be able to focus on the screen if it's just a plain screen - it's too close to your face. You can use some arrangement of lenses to create "fake distance".

Comment: The surface indeed is going to be a lense

Answer (score 2):

A very old magician's trick is to use a sheet of glass at 45 degrees instead of a mirror. Provided the ambient lighting is controlled, an audience looking at the surface will see both the surface and a reflection of what is on the screen.

Comment: [Pepper's Ghost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper%27s_ghost)

Comment: Indeed! When I was a boy, very many years ago, I was given a book entitled "Secrets of the Conjuror's Craft", which had a section all about Pepper's Ghost.

Comment: If i got it, I tried placing the screen at 45 deg with the glass(same as glass with 45deg), but the projection is at far corner that's hard to see, basically, i need to look from another 45deg :(